# Working with "old" ggplot2 code

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made ton of figures with ggplot 0.8.9 (which is what I'm still running).  Now I need to modify these figures to include legends.  I am running across all sorts of problems that are hard to solve because I am getting really confused about `theme` and `opts` and many SO answers that apply to later versions.

At this point, it seems like I need to update ggplot2 and rewrite all of my code just so I can have legends on my figures.  **Is this true?**  I've read the ggplot2 transition guide, it makes it seem true.

Here's what the old code looks like (does not produce a legend): And here is the data for the sake of reproducibility: [mean10v2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uy8ydfcls8iukiv/mean10v2.txt) and [stderr10](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eipapcald2w3gwl/stderr10.txt).

```
me10<-read.table("mean10v2.txt", header=TRUE)
se10<-read.table("stderr10.txt", header=TRUE)

ggplot() +
geom_ribbon(aes(x = me10[me10$trt=="CC", "tu"], ymin=(me10[me10$trt=="CC", "biomassA"]-    
  se10[se10$trt=="CC", "biomassA"]), ymax=(me10[me10$trt=="CC",  
  "biomassA"]+se10[se10$trt=="CC", "biomassA"])), alpha=0.25) +
geom_line(aes(me10[me10$trt=="CC", "tu"], y=me10[me10$trt=="CC", "biomassA"]), size=1)+  
geom_ribbon(aes(x = me10[me10$trt=="PF", "tu"], ymin=(me10[me10$trt=="PF", "biomassA"]- 
  se10[se10$trt=="PF", "biomassA"]), ymax=(me10[me10$trt=="PF", 
  "biomassA"]+se10[se10$trt=="PF", "biomassA"])), alpha=0.25) +
geom_line(aes(me10[me10$trt=="PF", "tu"], y=me10[me10$trt=="PF", "biomassA"]), 
  colour="red2", linetype="dashed", size=1) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(x = me10[me10$trt=="P", "tu"], ymin=(me10[me10$trt=="P", "biomassA"]-
  se10[se10$trt=="P", "biomassA"]), ymax=(me10[me10$trt=="P",   
  "biomassA"]+se10[se10$trt=="P", "biomassA"])), alpha=0.25) +
geom_line(aes(me10[me10$trt=="P", "tu"], y=me10[me10$trt=="P", "biomassA"]),    
  colour="blue3", linetype="dotted", size=1) + 
opts(panel.grid.minor = theme_blank()) +
opts(panel.grid.major = theme_blank()) +
opts(panel.background = theme_blank()) +
opts(axis.line = theme_segment()) +
opts(legend.position=c(.5,.5)) +
opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(size=12,vjust=-0.5)) +
opts(axis.title.y = theme_text(size=12,angle=90)) +
opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(colour="black", size=16)) +
opts(axis.text.y = theme_text(colour="black", size=16)) +
annotate("text", x = -Inf, y = Inf, label = "a", face="bold", hjust = -5, vjust=2, size     
  = 9) + 
ylab("") +
xlab("") +
ylim(0,2200)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating the `theme` parts is actually quite simple. You really just need to change `opts()` to `theme()` and replace `theme_*` with `element_*`. Some other names have changed, like you'll use `element_line` instead of `theme_segment`.

But more generally, you're using ggplot all wrong:

```
my_df <- me10[,c('trt','tu','biomassA')]
my_se <- setNames(se10[,c('trt','tu','biomassA')],c('trt','tu','se'))

my_df <- merge(my_df,my_se)

ggplot(data = my_df,aes(x = tu,y = biomassA)) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(group = trt,ymin = biomassA - se,ymax = biomassA + se),alpha = 0.25) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = trt,linetype = trt,colour = trt)) + 
    labs(x = "",y = "") + 
    ylim(0,2200) + 
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(),
          legend.position=c(.5,.5),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size=12,vjust=-0.5),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size=12,angle=90),
          axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size=16),
          axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=16)) + 
    annotate("text", x = -Inf, y = Inf, label = "a", face="bold", hjust = -5, vjust=2, size = 9)
```

[image]

Notice how much cleaner that is, and putting the data into an appropriate form only took three lines. Also note that there is absolutely no need to keep repeating the `opts()` or `theme()` calls for every....single....thing...you....set.

And then if you want to choose specific colors/linetypes for each group, you do *that* using the scale functions, not by setting them individually:

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values = c('black','red2','blue3')) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('solid','dashed','dotted'))
```

Comment: Thanks, @joran, this is such a huge help with this specific problem and with understanding ggplot2 better in general. I bought the book, but I struggle with applying the examples to my own data. This is really valuable to me.

Comment: @Nazer No problem. Figuring out the switch from `opts` to `theme` should generally just involve carefully studying the options listed in `?theme`. The switch to 0.9.0 had many big changes that were documented in some detail [here](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf).